# Can't access members of child class in polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class Book {
public:
    string title;
    int ID;
    virtual void S () = 0;
};

class Narnia : public Book {
public:
    int NarniaParts;
    virtual void S () {}
};

class HP : public Book {
public:
    int HPparts;
    virtual void S () {}
};

int main () 
{   
    Book * s = new Narnia;
    s->   //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS




    return 0;
}
```

So I wrote this small piece of code with one super-class Book and two subclasses Narnia and HP. When I do

```
Book * s = new Narnia;
```

my "s->" can not access the member function of class Narnia "NarniaParts". It can access all the members of the super class Book (title, ID and S) but not the member NarniaParts of the object of class Narnia. Can someone please explain why I s-> can't access NarniaParts? Thank you!

Comment: `NarniaParts` is not a member function (as your question text implies).

Comment: @jrok No but it IS a data member of class Narnia any object created of class Narnia should have it's own data member in it in any case? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: You think about it in the correct way, but you are telling the compiler that `s` is a `Book`, which does not have the data member you want to access. You need a pointer-to-Narnia to access `NarniaParts`, as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the compiler doesn't know that `s` is a `Narnia` until run-time, therefore, It won't let you treat `s` like a `Narnia` during compile time unless you specifically tell it that `s` is a `Narnia`(casting)

---

You're doing your polymorphism backwards.

What it appears that you want to do is  make a virtual method called `BookParts` in your `Book` Class, and have each derived class override the `BookParts` method instead of having their own method.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this without using type casting?

Comment: @TheAbster declare `s` as a `Narnia` instead of as a `Book`

Comment: Well, basically, I need to make an array of Book pointers make some indices "new Narnia"'s and some "new HP"'s. So to do that I would need the ** to point to Book, no?

Comment: @TheAbster  I've updated my question, but what you might want to do is to make a virtual `BookParts` method in your `Book` class, and then override that class in your sub-classes, instead of methods like `NarniaParts`.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to access derived-class functions from a base pointer (unless you use virtual functions). You need to cast to `Narnia*` before you can use the derived class functions. For example:

```
Narnia* n=dynamic_cast<Narnia*>(s);
```

`s` and `n` will point to the same object, but when using `n` you can access derived-class functions in Narnia. If the cast fails, `n` will be equal to `NULL`.

Comment: "It is impossible to access derived-class functions from a base pointer." Unless they are virtual in base and overridden in derived?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the case here. The question refers to a public member of the derived class. Edited my answer for completeness, though.

Comment: Derived classes have no functions  (other than virtuals), I think that's the source of confusion here :)